# how to post dynamically generated html table when form submitted?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a form that will contain a  html table which allows users can add or delete rows from it. That will works fine .

```
/*add row*/
function add_Items(itemtypeid, itemid, reqqty) {
    var mode = 1;
    var pstSettings = {
        url: 'ajax_Items/' + itemid + '/' + mode
        callback: function (data) {
            var dyntd = "";
            var hidval = "";
            var $response = $(data);
            var resitmname = $response.filter('#Item_Name').text();
            var resitmdesc = $response.filter('#Item_Descrip').text();
            dyntd = "<td><label>" + itemid + "</label></td>";
            dyntd += "<td><label>" + resitmname + "</label></td>";
            dyntd += "<td><label>" + resitmdesc + "</label></td>";
            dyntd += "<td><label>" + reqqty + "</label></td>";
            hidval += '<input type="hidden" name="itemid"  value=' + itemid + ' />';
            hidval += '<input type="hidden" name="reqitem"  value=' + reqqty + ' />';
            dyntd += '<td>' + hidval + '<input type="button" name="min" class="minus" value="-" />';

            $('.item-result-table tr:last').after('<tr>' + dyntd + '</tr>');
        }
    };
    post_Call(pstSettings);
}
}

/* delete row */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item-result-table').delegate('.minus', 'click', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

But now my problem is how to submit the html table in a form, because of all are html tags not input type tags . I have added a hidden tag . But it also creates problem that it only takes the  first element , others are ignored. Is any other method existing to submit this html table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are only getting one input is because you defined it wrong, you need to define it as array:

```
<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]"  value=' + itemid + ' />
<input type="hidden" name="reqitem[]"  value=' + reqqty + ' />'
```

and then in PHP:

```
$_POST['itemid'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use the `$.ajax` jquery function. You can serialize all your inputs in the form like this:

```
$("#btn_submit").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).closest("#div_content").find("#form").attr( 'action' ),
        type: 'post',
        data: $(this).closest("#div_content").find("#form").serialize(),
    }).done( function(msg) {
        //console.log("ok");
    }).fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        //console.log("fail");
    }); 
});
```

With the "serialize" you can send all the variables and on the controller you can read the variables with `$_POST` and the name of the input.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply . firstly hearing about the serialize inputs . I am going to try this one.